# How can I restrict the access of certain users to "retrieve secret value" from the secret manager or to give access only to certain users

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

How can I restrict the access of certain users to "retrieve secret value" from the secret manager or to give access only to certain users? How could I do this from boto3 or even from the console.

Comment: you can provide required access by attaching a permission policy to an IAM user directly or to an IAM group, attach secretsmanager:GetSecretValue to retrieve secret.

Comment: For each user we have created in scret manager a secrets where everyone will put thei secretkey and access key, and I would like a user not to be able to see the credentials of another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS docs have a [tutorial on ABAC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_attribute-based-access-control.html) (Attribute Based Access Control; a.k.a tagging) that describes how to do this. The tutorial is a bit of a long read though, and to sum it up, you can put a tag on the secrets and tag on your users/roles and compare the tag values in the IAM policies with the condition:

```
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:ResourceTag/MYTAGNAME": "${aws:PrincipalTag/MYTAGNAME}"
        }
    },
```

You can also do the same [using resource policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206554/grant-cross-account-secretsmanager-access-to-an-iam-role-that-does-not-yet-exist/59218645#59218645) on the secrets.